# Android.mk phony package builds with mma, but does not build with make

Tags: makefile, android-source

With Android 9 build system, I was able to use `BUILD_PHONY_PACKAGE` and `LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES` to be able to execute custom builds in Android.mk files, however, now I switched to Android 11, and somehow can't get it working. If you are unfamiliar with the phony package building template with Android build system, please see https://kristianrumberg.wordpress.com/2016/02/13/android-local-module-based-on-custom-target/.

The weird thing is, if I compile with `mma`, then it builds successfully, however if I do `make -j8`, then the targets specified in the makefile are not executed at all. I wonder what I am missing. Please see the following example:

```
mypackage_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH := $(mypackage_LOCAL_PATH)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := mypackage
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

mypackage_ANDROID_API ?= 28
mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_CROSS_COMPILE := aarch64-linux-android$(mypackage_ANDROID_API)-
mypackage_LIBDIR := lib64
mypackage_ARCH := arm64
mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_PATH := toolchain/android-ndk/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86_64
mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_BIN_PATH := $(mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_PATH)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin

mypackage_ANDROID_DIR := $(shell pwd)
mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_DIR := $(mypackage_ANDROID_DIR)/$(mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_PATH)
mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_BIN_DIR := $(mypackage_ANDROID_DIR)/$(mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_BIN_PATH)

mypackage_SOURCE_PATH = $(mypackage_LOCAL_PATH)/mypackage
mypackage_BUILD_PATH = $(OUT_DIR)/standalone/build/mypackage

$(mypackage_BUILD_PATH):
    ....
    ....

$(mypackage_BUILD_PATH)/apps/mypackage: $(mypackage_BUILD_PATH)
    $(hide) \
        ANDROID_NDK=$(mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_DIR) \
        CROSS_COMPILE=$(mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_CROSS_COMPILE) \
        PATH=$(mypackage_ANDROID_NDK_BIN_DIR):$$PATH \
        $(MAKE) -C "${mypackage_BUILD_PATH}" --silent \
            DESTDIR="$(mypackage_ANDROID_DIR)"/"$(PRODUCT_OUT)" \
            generate_apps \
            install_programs

LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES := $(mypackage_BUILD_PATH)/apps/mypackage
include $(BUILD_PHONY_PACKAGE)
```

I made sure that there is no path variable here that is not defined or pointing to wrong place. I also verified that the problem is that the target `$(mypackage_BUILD_PATH)/apps/mypackage` is not executed. Rest of the file is executed. I would have expected that the target executed since it is specified in `LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES` variable.

I just wonder why it works as it is with `mma`, but it doesn't with `make -j8`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Does mypackage_BUILD_PATH contain spaces? (GNU Make cannot handle that). 2) Is the workspace clean prior `make -j8`? If `mma` and `make` is supposed to do the same thing, make will probably think there is nothing to do. You can try `make -B -j8` to make regardless of timestamps. 3) Is `mypackage` a directory? `make` does not do well with directories.

Comment: Unless there's something else not shown here, the default target if you run `make` will be the `mypacakge_BUILD_PATH` directory.  Since it has no prerequisites, if that directory exists at all then there's nothing left for make to do and it will exit.  I have no idea what `mma` is but maybe it invokes make with some special target name, not the default.

Comment: @Andreas mypackage_BUILD_PATH is a path that does not exist. It contains no spaces. Before both commands I do source envsetup and then lunch. mypackage is a directory under external/. But at the same time it is the name of the module that I'm trying to build.

Comment: @MadScientist I want default target to be $(mypackage_BUILD_PATH)/apps/mypackage since it is specified in LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: I don't know if there's anything wrong with it, but that's not what your makefile does (as shown here).  The **first** explicit target in a makefile is always the default target make will build if you don't specify otherwise, somehow.  The first explicit target shown here is `$(mypackage_BUILD_PATH)`, not `$(mypackage_BUILD_PATH)/apps/mypackage`